# wordpress set user logged in on a specific condition

Tags: wordpress

I want to set `userloggedin` in wordpress on a specific condition. I am using the follwoing code :

```
$userid = $u[0]->id;
        set_transient('eexamhall_userid',$userid,10800);
        wp_set_current_user( $userid, 'userids' );
```

but when I am checking this `is_user_logged_in` then it is not giving any output.

How can I set user logged in

Answer (score 1):

wp_set_current_user() just sets the current user, it doesn't login the user.
To login any user you need to add auth function:

```
wp_set_current_user( $userid, 'userids' );
wp_set_auth_cookie(  $userid );
//this is optional: do_action( 'wp_login', 'user_login_here' );
```

Comment: It sets isloggedin condition true. But I want to use another menu when this condition is true